# Why can't I use module in my lex file?

Tags: ocaml, ocamllex

This is what I currently have for my `mll` file which runs just fine.

```
{ type token = EOF | Word of string }

rule token = parse
    | eof { EOF }
    | ['a'-'z' 'A'-'Z']+ as word {Word(word)}
    | _ { token lexbuf }
{
    let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel stdin in
    let wordlist = 
        let rec next l = 
            match token lexbuf with
                EOF -> l
            | Word(s) -> next (s::l)
        in next []
    in

    List.iter print_endline wordlist
}
```

I do `ocamllex a.mll` and then `ocamlc -o a a.ml`. Running `./a < a.mll` will print out all the strings that exist in the mll file, which is exactly what I expect it to do.

However, if I add `module StringMap = Map.Make(String)` just before the `List.iter` call, I get a syntax error...
`File "a.mll", line 17, characters 4-10:` where line 17 is the line with `module` and 4-10 is the word `module`.

I cannot figure out why adding this line is giving me a syntax error... If I enter the same code into toplevel it works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that the code generated by ocamllex ends up inside a function. You can't declare a global-style module inside a function.

However you can declare a local module like this:

```
let module StringMap = Map.Make(String) in ...
```

Example:

```
# let fgm () =
      module StringMap = Map.Make(String)
      StringMap.cardinal StringMap.empty;;
Error: Syntax error
# let flm () =
      let module StringMap = Map.Make(String) in
      StringMap.cardinal StringMap.empty;;
val flm : unit -> int = <fun>
# flm ();;
- : int = 0
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense then. The documentation on ocaml.org doesn't specify that module is a global-style declaration, or that you need to prefix it with let when inside a function. Thanks!

Comment: What it boils down to is that `module M = ...` is a definition but `let module M = ... in ...` is an expression. A definition is allowed only at the outer level of a module (such as a source file), but an expression is the core of OCaml's syntax, showing up many places.

Comment: Is it necessary to have the `in ...` part?

Comment: Yes, it is necessary. The module is local to the expression after `in`. Without `in` it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Hmm, so what exactly is `cardinal` and `empty` doing? I know cardinal is the number of bindings and empty is just an empty map, but I don't get the syntax.

Comment: cardinal is a function, not a number. The empty map is the parameter of the function. It's just an example, it doesn't calculate anything interesting :-)

Comment: You'll have to show your code to get useful comments. Maybe open up a new question.